# Can I re enter France with a demande de duplicata pour un titre de séjour?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, france, consulates

I have a 10-year France titre de séjour but it was lost. I applied for a duplicate but I haven't received it yet. It's been more than two months.

I have only a “demande de duplicata pour un titre de séjour”. I need to go to the UK on an emergency. Can I re-enter France with that receipt of duplicate? Or is there a process to come back to France? Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Are you a British citizen?

Comment: something is missing before "D'une". Could it be "Récépissé"?

Comment: (At first glance I would say no, because it only indicates that you requested a duplicate, not that you'll obtain one, or even that the titre de séjour is valid)

Comment: This may be more relevant for https://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: I vaguely remember something like a récépissé for a renewal is valid while a récépissé for a first request isn’t, and that’s what https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F12189 says, but they do not mention the duplicata case (and the renewal case doesn’t apply for you as you would need the expired TS in addition to the récépissé).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the document you have is enough but if all else fails, there is a procedure intended to cover *force majeure* cases and emergencies for people who are present legally but do not have a document allowing them to come back to France, it's called a “visa de retour préfectoral”. You have to apply for that at the *préfecture* before leaving. Similarly, if you lose your residence permit while traveling abroad, consulates can issue a “visa de retour consulaire”.

As an example, here is the [form used by the Alpes-Maritimes préfecture](https://www.alpes-maritimes.gouv.fr/contenu/telechargement/33254/259304/file/Formulaire_demande_visa_retour.pdf) but others should be similar. I have no idea how likely you are to get it, it's at the discretion of the prefect and probably depends on how serious the emergency is. You'll have to explain that in a letter in French.